# Date validation error

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to validate date input and getting the below error even after using to_char or to_date. Can someone help me what is wrong in the below code

```
validfrmdate timestamp;
BEGIN

      validfrmdate := to_timestamp('20170814000001','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('fromdate' || validfrmdate);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('indate' || input_frmdate);

        --IF input_frmdate <= to_char(validfrmdate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') THEN
        IF input_frmdate <= validfrmdate  THEN
 ------
```

When I try to execute the above getting the below error

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 10
fromdate14-AUG-17 12.00.01.000000 AM
indate20170813094755
Process exited.
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `input_frmdate` is a string, not a timestamp.
Try to convert it into a timestsamp:

```sql
declare
  validfrmdate     timestamp;
  ts_input_frmdate timestamp;
begin

  validfrmdate := to_timestamp('20170814000001','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
  ts_input_frmdate := to_timestamp(input_frmdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');

  dbms_output.put_line('fromdate' || validfrmdate);
  dbms_output.put_line('indate' || ts_input_frmdate);

  if ts_input_frmdate <= validfrmdate then
  ...
  end if;

end;
```